# How to design a generic search method for searching through any attribute in an index

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to design a generic search method for searching through any attribute in an index. I would like to take in a generic Map as my input where it allows you to describe the attribute and the corresponding value which you intend to map it to and I would prefer the output is available in a paginated fashion.

```
For example it could be something like, search all User's which has
    gender = 'm' AND first_name starts contains "ack" AND birth_date between 1970 and 1980
```

I am looking to build it using an interface which allows me to build the query based on the inputs provided in a dynamic fashion. Does spring-data-elasticsearch provide any higher level constructs to build such queries and return results in a paginated fashion. How should I approach this?

```
@PostMapping("/search")
public Iterable<User> search(@RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> inputs, 
    Pageable pageable) {
    return userService.search(inputs, pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.1.3/reference/html/), Section 7.6, "Queries"

The link to this section seems to be broken, so click on 7.5 and scroll down a bit.

There the 3 possibilities that Spring Data Elasticsearch offers (`CriteriaQuery`, `StringQuery` and `NatveSearchQuery`) are described.

Comment: How should the search criteria be passed to the controller, if you have to dynamically express your query criterion from the user interface

Comment: How any information is passed from the UI to a controller is out of scope for Spring Data Elasticsearch